# Click image Page 1 and Display the same image on Page 2 (form). HTML coding

Tags: html, forms, image

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have created page 1 with 9 images. When any one image is clicked, I have it linked to redirect to page 2 (the images are not html coded).

I would like to create an html on page 2 that grabs the image the user clicked on page 1.

I'm a newbie coder. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: You need at least javascript, or create a static pages

Comment: Toda Raba Alon. I'm not sure that answers my question though.

Comment: @CFLLithoplate your question is very badly asked. We will not code for you. Make a try, write something, then we could help you. The question is very borad.

Comment: @HassenCh. If I knew the code, why would I ask?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not made to write code for you. If you don't know anything about code, I would suggest you go ahead and take a course. There are plenty that are free everywhere. Go learn mode about JavaScript for example, database... The question that you asked simply couldn't be answered here. It's a mini project!